# Multiple touch detection in Cocoa/iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone

I am in a strange problem-

1. I am using a virtual D-pad.
2. So when i move my virtual joystick player moves , But if i tap/press my button at that time(while my touch remains on joystick) press/tap button not works, because  touchBegin/touchMove not called since my previous touch on joystick remains.
3. So what to do if i want player moving with action(by pressing button).

Comment: which virtual D-pad library are you using ?

Comment: Own Dpad ,thats not the factor, I just want to know if one finger is remain on touch screen, then if i touch again the touch screen then CCtouchBegan should/ should not called ??if not called then what is the way to detect touch again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to turn on multiple touch support by adding the following line in the application delegate's `applicationDidFinishLaunching` :

```
EAGLView *glView = ...

[glView setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];
```

Then your `ccTouchBegan` will called for 2nd, 3rd touches and so on.